# Case-When/HasNext variable input loop

Tags: t-sql, case-when

I am honestly having trouble articulating this question to my co-workers, so please go easy on me. I can elaborate if needed.

So here is the deal, I have a theoretical question about SQL's Case When statement. This isn't a specific situation that I need help with, it is just a complex question I need answered about the abilities of the T-SQL language, which I want to know for my own future purposes.

I know that in Java you can creat loops and use the .hasNext() method to continuosly retrieve input from a source (the keyboard for example), and by doing this you can essentially create a loop that does [some action] until you run out of input.

I would like to know if I can use a similar sort of function (correct me if function is not the right terminology) that I can use along with a Case When statement in T-SQL.

Here is some psuedo code for example:

```
case when [Column Y has next] then 'X'
```

Essentially I want to know if I can tell a Case When funciton to execute continuosly until it runs out of values or encounters a null value.

Please let me know if I am on the right track here, my brain is kind of stuck somewhere between the object oriented world of Java and the relational DB world of SQL. All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: The range of data that the `case` operates on is defined by the `where` and `join`(s) of `select` statement it is part of.

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve? For example: "I'm trying to find the first value in a column that's greater than 3". There's probably a simple SQL answer to that. But you have to be thinking in terms of that and not the low-level mechanics of how you'd solve the problem in an imperative language like Java.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I don't honestly have a "specific" problem, I was just wondring if the SQL language understood the concept of a column having another value in a data set.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, G Mastros pretty much nailed it for me! Sorry to ask such a tricky question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case-When is basically a row operation.  Specifically, you need to think about the set of data you are working with based on joins and where clauses, and then think about the case-when operator running against each row in the result set.  Because of this, there is no concept of previous row, next row or "has next".

That being said, there's always a way to accomplish what you want.  Generically speaking, I would usually recommend a "self join".  This is really just a special case of a regular type of join (inner, left, right, full and cross).  The difference here is that instead of joining two different tables, you join the same table back to itself.  If you introduce a Row_Number function and include that in the where clause, you can effectively join one row to the next row, which would effectively give you a way to accomplish a "has next" functionality.

Comment: So when used, the Case-When is operating on an entire set of data (specified by the join statements and what I have selected in my query) at a time. It doesn't execute on a row by row basis, essentially? If this is true then I understand what you are saying, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also, I have never thought of the idea of a self join, thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely use that in the future.

Comment: Think of it this way... if you run your query with "Select *" and all your joins and where clause conditions, then Case-When will only have access to the data on each row.  More specifically, a case-when statement does not have access to data on another row.  By doing a self join, you can effectively get data from another row by having the query return it on the same row.